# DyanmoDB query to fetch item using non partition key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I have requirement to fetch the item from dynamodb based on the order id(not the partition key).

If the order id is *123456* as mentioned the in the above example I should get this item.

Can somebody please let me know if it is possible to achieve this. If yes, how?

**DynamoDB Table**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="SomeTable")
public class SomeTable {
private String id;
private String name;
private List<Order> orders;

 @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


}
```

**Class 2**

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Order {
private String id;
private String name;
}
```

**DynamoDB Table Data**

```
 "Items": [
     {
         "orders": {
             "L": [
                 {
                     "M": {
                         "name": {
                             "S": "xyz"
                         },
                         "id": {
                             "S": "123456"
                         }
                     }
                 }
             ]
         },
         "id": {
             "S": "789"
         },
         "name": {
             "S": "abcd"
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Scan` not a `Query`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

When you do the scan your `AttributeValue` needs to be a `String Set`, not just a `String`.

In your `FilterExpression` use the condition `CONTAINS` with your `AttributeValue`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

Comment: `Map<String, AttributeValue> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("name", new AttributeValue().withS("xyz"));
  map.put("id", new AttributeValue().withS("123456"));
  
  Map<String, AttributeValue> eav2 = new HashMap<>();
  eav2.put(":orders", new AttributeValue().withM(map));
  DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
    .withFilterExpression("contains (orders, :orders)")
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav2 );

  List<SomeTable > list= mapper.parallelScan(SomeTable .class,
    scanExpression, 1);`

Comment: This above code works but I have to pass whole map but in my case I can't pass whole map, I will have only id and not the name. Is there any way I can achieve this?